# Streaming live camera feed (RTSP) using J2ME on Nokia phones

Tags: java-me, camera, nokia, rtsp, live-streaming

I want to create an App that can play a live camera feed on nokia devices.

I created a sample app as described here:

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_play_video_streaming_in_Java_ME

Using this I am able to play youtube or file based rtsp streams but not direct camera feeds.

Further details

- IP camera is sending live camera captures as feed in RTSP format
- MPEG4 format
- It is possible to play this feed on RealPlayer and VLC in desktop systems
- Not able to play this feed using RealPlayer on Mobile.

How do I create an App that can play live feed.

It is also ok for me if i can get some existing media players which are capable of playing live feeds.